# Passing Values from one activity to another, using Object and getting a resource not found error.

Tags: java, android, object, message-passing

I have two pages in my application, I am passing one certain value from one page to another:

**Class Level Definition: (From the sending class)**

```
 BuyGold50 BG5 = null;
```

**In onCreate() of the same class:**

```
 BG5 = new BuyGold50();
```

**In a certain function of the first activity--Before calling intent to second Activity**

```
 BG5.SetPrice(Gold);
```

================================================================================

**Code of the BuyGold50 class**

```
public class BuyGold50 extends Activity {

    public static String B;
    static int X;

    public void SetPrice(String Price) {
        B = Price;
        X = Integer.parseInt(B);
    }

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.buy_gold50);
        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        tv.setText(X);
    }

}
```

**Log Cat**

```
07-30 11:59:07.304: E/AndroidRuntime(615): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-30 11:59:07.304: E/AndroidRuntime(615): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.Geet/com.Geet.BuyGold50}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0xb34
07-30 11:59:07.304: E/AndroidRuntime(615):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
07-30 11:59:07.304: E/AndroidRuntime(615):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
07-30 11:59:07.304: E/AndroidRuntime(615):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
07-30 11:59:07.304: E/AndroidRuntime(615):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
07-30 11:59:07.304: E/AndroidRuntime(615):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-30 11:59:07.304: E/AndroidRuntime(615):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-30 11:59:07.304: E/AndroidRuntime(615):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
07-30 11:59:07.304: E/AndroidRuntime(615):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-30 11:59:07.304: E/AndroidRuntime(615):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-30 11:59:07.304: E/AndroidRuntime(615):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
07-30 11:59:07.304: E/AndroidRuntime(615):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
07-30 11:59:07.304: E/AndroidRuntime(615):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-30 11:59:07.304: E/AndroidRuntime(615): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0xb34
07-30 11:59:07.304: E/AndroidRuntime(615):  at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:201)
07-30 11:59:07.304: E/AndroidRuntime(615):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2857)
07-30 11:59:07.304: E/AndroidRuntime(615):  at com.Geet.BuyGold50.onCreate(BuyGold50.java:21)
07-30 11:59:07.304: E/AndroidRuntime(615):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
07-30 11:59:07.304: E/AndroidRuntime(615):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
07-30 11:59:07.304: E/AndroidRuntime(615):  ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
 tv.setText(X);
```

with

```
tv.setText(String.valueOf(X));
```

if you pass an int as argument to setText, internally, android will look for a String with that id. If it does not exist it will throws `Resources$NotFoundException`

Answer (score 1):

> You are trying to set int value in

```
tetview.setText() or Toast.makeText(), which it will take as string resource id.
```

> So try to give int value in like this

```
.setText(""+intvalue) or Toast.makeText(context,""+intvalue,..)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I learnt it today that text view only needs a string value, was aware of the toast thing!

Answer (score 1):

The error has occurred at `com.Geet.BuyGold50.onCreate(BuyGold50.java:21)`, see your logcat for this.
This exception occurred due to the fact that a `String` was not found which you had passed named `Gold` in first activity.